# Flink at least once Processing without checkpointing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, streaming

Is it possible to achieve at least once processing guarantee while consuming from kafka without checkpointing ?
Duplicate messages are accepted in sink.
The only requiremere here is no data loss.
Like when the consumer polls the record from kafka and it fails in between without processing completely, then the record should get replayed.
Is there a way we can achieve without checkpointing enabled ?

Manually commiting offsets can be one way, but not sure if there are other better ways to do this.

Found this from flink doc:

Flink can guarantee exactly-once state updates to user-defined state only when the source participates in the snapshotting mechanismsource flink doc: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/guarantees.htmlDoes this mean we can achieve at least once without checkpointing ? I didn't find any specific requirement for at least once processing.

Answer (score 2):

No, all of Flink's processing guarantees (except for NONE) rely on the snapshotting mechanism of checkpointing and savepointing.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box solution - If there is a good correlation between the source and sink data, you can continuously validated the Kafka topic offset and the number of sink events and retransmit events from the source if a gap is being built by changing offset configuration.

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#starting-offset

https://medium.com/@mitch_datorios/first-time-kafka-flink-integration-stream-processing-insights-b55e0a4858dd

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do that, you risk losing on capabilities like processing events in the right order.